# Approach to close/reopen database

Tags: android, database

When I am dealing with a usual `Activity`, then I open a database in `onCreate` and close it in `onStop`. When I deal with tab activities, then I add another open in `onResume` and another close in `onPause`.

So the code looks like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mDB.open();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mDB.open();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mDB.close();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    mDB.close();
}
```

Is this too much of opening and closing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. You are just managing lifecycle of the application, which is a very good thing.

Comment: agreed, you should always close your db connection when you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

I think close database after open it in a code block is a better way. Because you can guarantee your database will close if there are some unwanted bugs in your activity's life cycle.

Comment: Hm it seems that yourself and a compiler think the same. I keep getting a warning that a cursor remains open although I close the DB in onStop. I will post another Q on this topic.